# Why nginx selects server block with _ server_name?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My simple nginx.conf:

```
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens on;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /_nginx_logs/access.log;
    error_log /_nginx_logs/error.log;
    gzip on;

    server {
        server_name www.example.pro;

        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        return 301 https://example.pro$request_uri;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.pro/fullchain.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.pro/privkey.pem";        
    }

    server {
        server_name example.pro

        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.pro/fullchain.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.pro/privkey.pem";        

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7500;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name _;
        listen 80 default_server;

        location / {
            root /projects/site-stub;
        }
    }
}
```

When I open my site as *https://example.pro* everything is ok.

When I open my site as *http://example.pro*, nginx answers from server block with `server_name _`.

Why? IP and port are the same, `server_name` value has exact word for `Host` header, but `server_name example.pro` not works for `http://`.
But it works good for `https://`!

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the `server_name` statement in the second server block.

Comment: Big thanks! I spent a day solving the problem. And nginx kept printing that the syntax is ok after `nginx -t` command.

Comment: Without semicolon it transformed intro 3 host names: `example.pro` , `listen`, and `80`,